# Eventlistener for an input "form"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a common problem I have no good way to handle:

On a web page I display an input form when a button is clicked. Behind the form I put a background that dim the page:

```
var bgDiv = document.createElement("div");
var formDiv = document.createElement("div");
bgDiv.appendChild(formDiv);
document.body.appendChild(bgDiv);
```

With ids and css something like this:

```
#zreaderwp-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.7);
    z-index: 100;
}
#zreader-form {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background: white;
}
```

I attach an eventlistener to bgDiv in a hope that ESC should hide the form:

```
        bgDiv.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            console.log("ev.keyCode", ev.keyCode);
            if (27 == ev.keyCode) {
                console.log("was 27");
                bgDiv.style.display = "none";
            }
        });
```

To my disappointment this never works as I expect it to. The reason is of course that focus is not always inside bgDiv (though it visually seems to be that).

Is there a good and simple way to handle this?

UPDATE: I created a fiddle to illustrate the problem a bit better, http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/Musqs/1/. As can be seen there moving the event handler does not solve the problem.

Comment: It'd really help us if you created a JSFiddle

Comment: Good idea, @SomeKittensUx2666. I have created a fiddle, see above.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide `bigDiv` whenever `esc` is pressed globally, add the event listener to `document` itself (though `stopPropagation()` could cause some issues, so I've moved it inside the if statement, modified for accuracy.):

```
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
        console.log("ev.keyCode", ev.keyCode);
        if (27 == ev.keyCode && bgDiv.style.display !== "none") {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            console.log("was 27");
            bgDiv.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
```

Additionally, use triple equals `===` in your if statement.  It probably won't change much here, but is a good habit to get into.  For more details, see: [== vs ===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons?rq=1)

Fiddle answer [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Musqs/6/).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem, please see the fiddle.

Comment: @Leo I've updated my answer with a fixed version of your fiddle.

Comment: How does this not solve your problem?  The Fiddle I posted has the function you've requested.

Comment: doc-input still sees the ESC. And I do not have any control over the event handlers attached to doc-input.

Comment: What do you mean by that?  Please be specific.

Comment: When I press ESC I get the alert from doc-input. Does not that happen to you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48786/discussion-between-somekittens-ux2666-and-leo)

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7vgrx/3/)

Attach it to document instead and don't stop the event from propogating when its a key press inside the input.

Here you go

```
var docInp = document.getElementById("doc-input");
docInp.focus();
docInp.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev){
    if (27 !== ev.keyCode && bgDiv.style.display !== "none") {
        // we won't stop event propogation if the ESC key was pressed and the bgDiv was visible
        ev.stopPropagation();
    }
    alert("Hi, it's me, docInp? Did u want something?");
});
var bgDiv = document.createElement("div");
bgDiv.setAttribute("id","bg");
var formDiv = document.createElement("div");
formDiv.setAttribute("id","form");
bgDiv.appendChild(formDiv);
formDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Press ESC!"));
document.body.appendChild(bgDiv);


document.addEventListener("keydown", listenToKeys, false);

function listenToKeys(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    if (27 == ev.keyCode) {
        bgDiv.style.display = "none";
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", listenToKeys, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly does this improve on my answer?

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 Well i never made a attempt to improve your answer.. maybe we both were writing at the same time.. but my answer removes the event listener when it should not be listening :)

Comment: Thanks, but this does unfortunately not solve the problem. Please see the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit hesitating to answer my own question, but since others may face the same problem it looks most helpful to me. After chatting with @SomeKittens Ux2666 yesterday and struggling with the problem that focus will not stay inside "bg" I found a solution that I think is reasonable, see http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/Musqs/31/.

This solution uses "focusout" (which is unfortunately not supported by FF at the moment, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/focusout):

```
        bgDiv.addEventListener("focusout", function(ev){
            // Fix-me: Won't currently work in FF, but it is not
            // really essential and FF will probably support this
            // later.
            ev.stopPropagation();
            var to = ev.relatedTarget;
            var from = ev.target;
            console.log("bg got focusout, to", to, "from", from);
            var inBg = false;
            n = 0;
            while (!inBg && to && n++ < 5) {
                to = to.parentNode;
                inBg = to === bgDiv;
            }
            if (!inBg) {
                console.log("trying to keep focus in bg");
                from.focus();
            }
        });
```

The other half of the solution is where to add the ESC keydown eventlistener. That has been addressed in the answer by @SomeKittens and @Lucky Soni, thanks. (But the eventlistener may actually stay on "bg" when the problem with focus has been solved!)

Comment: There is no reason to hesitate to [answer your own question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you've found a solution and none of the previously posted answers were adequate.

Comment: Oh, yes there is. My feeling for it. ;-) -- Thanks @AdiInbar.